# Convert day of the year to date

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Currently I failed to convert a day of the year integer to a formatted string / date like **mm-dd**. I tried some different solution approaches, including most of the solutions which are posted here - without success.

I expect this: Today is the **359** day of the year - and it should be converted to **12-25**

Comment: There is not much about these stuff. My first hope was this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11937326/how-to-convert-day-of-year-to-date-in-iphone), but the guys who marked it as duplicate didn't understand the question. I also google it and consulted my books without success. Most of the articles and questions are in the other way > date to day of the year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents* components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setDay:359];
[components setYear:2013];
[components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
NSDate* day359 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
```

output

```
2013-12-25 00:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: Thanks - this works. I forget to set the year and also set the wrong timeZone ;)

Answer (score 1):

Really?, even without knowing objective-c it seems quite stright forward:

```
const JANUARY = 31;
const FEBURARY = JANUARY + 28;
const MARCH = FEBRUARY + 31;
...
const NOVEMBER = OCTOBER + 30;

if( day < JANUARY ) { dd = day; mm = 1; }
else if( day < FEBRUARY ) { dd = day - JANUARY; mm = 2 }
else if( day < MARCH ) { dd = day - FEBRUARY; mm =  3 }
...
else if( day < NOVEMBER ) { dd = day - OCTOBER; mm = 11 }
else { dd == day - NOVEMBER; mm = 12 }

print "$dd/$mm";
```

Comment: @adali, yes you're right, but this is such a trivial question, let the OP do some work

Comment: @ilomambo I guess to "go by feet" is not necessary :)

Comment: Hard Code ftw! What are you going to do if the Mayan Calendar resets again?